# Using Tensorflow checkpoint to restore model in C++

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, deep-learning

I've trained a network that I implemented with Tensorflow using Python. In the end, I saved the model with tf.train.Saver(). And now I would like to use C++ to make predictions using this pre trained network.

How can I do that ? Is there a way to convert checkpoint so I can use it with tiny-dnn or Tensorflow C++ ?

Any idea is welcome :) thank you !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably should export the model in the [SavedModel format](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/saved_model/README.md), which encapsulates the computational graph and the saved variables (`tf.train.Saver` only saves the variables, so you'd have to save the graph anyway).

You can then load the saved model in C++ using [`LoadSavedModel`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.h).

The exact invocation would depend on what the inputs and outputs of your model are. But the Python code would look something like so:

```
# You'd adjust the arguments here according to your model
signature = tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.predict_signature_def(                                                                        
  inputs={'image': input_tensor}, outputs={'scores': output_tensor})                                                                         


builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder('/tmp/my_saved_model')                                                                    

builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(                                                                                                        
   sess=sess,                                                                                                                    
   tags=[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],                                                                                             
   signature_def_map={                                                                                                       
 tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:                                                                
        signature                                                                                                                        
})                                                                                                                                       

builder.save()
```

And then in C++ you'd do something like this:

```
tensorflow::SavedModelBundle model;
auto status = tensorflow::LoadSavedModel(session_options, run_options, "/tmp/my_saved_model", {tensorflow::kSavedModelTagServe}, &model);
if (!status.ok()) {
   std::cerr << "Failed: " << status;
   return;
}
// At this point you can use model.session
```

(Note that using the SavedModel format will also allow you to serve models using [TensorFlow Serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/tfserve), if that makes sense for your application)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Seems like that's exactly what I needed ! I'm going to try it and I'll tell you ! Thank you !

Comment: tensorflow::SavedModelBundle model; generates google protobuf error.